# parameters and calling methods to print

Tags: java, methods, parameters

I am doing a programming course but my recent homework is causing me some problems as I'm being asked to do things which I have no idea how.

One of my questions

A method called printResult() that takes an integer representing the final score at a computer game and a boolean indicating whether the player won or not. If the player won, the method should print.
Player 1 wins with  point(s)
Otherwise
Player 1 loses with  point(s)

```
void printResult(boolean winner, int score){

    if(winner == true)
        println("Player 1 wins with " + score + " point(s)");
    else        
        println("Players 1 loses with " + score + " point(s)");
}
```

That's all I have so far.

I don't know how to set the code up to read if the player wins or not as I don't have the scores.

Also I'm having issues getting Java to return two figures as one
instead of 1+2 = 3 I need it to return 12.
so return 1 + 2 doesn't work.

and lastly how do I get Java to print information from other methods?

I have a question where I need to print a line that takes information from 2 other methods I've made.

Now write a method called getPersonDescription() that takes a name, a boolean indicating whether the person is female (if true, male if false), and that person’s age. The method should return a String like this:
James is middle aged. At 35 he has 30 years left until he is geriatric.
Or, if the parameters were different the return value might be.
Sally is a teenager. At 14 she has 6 years left until she is a young adult.

Fairly obviously the method should use calls to getMaturityLevel() and yearsUntilNextMaturityLevel() to achieve part of its task. Note that the method will never be used to describe people who are already antique.

Thankyou in advance

Comment: What is that you exactly want?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't so much a programming question, but a clarification of the assignment.

> I don't know how to set the code up to read if the player wins or not
>   as I don't have the scores.

Well neither do any of us.  We don't even know to which game you are referring, so we can't tell you how to find the score.

> Also I'm having issues getting Java to return two figures as one instead of 1+2 = 3 I need it to return 12. so return 1 + 2 doesn't work.

That statement is unclear.  What do you mean return two figures as one?  Java methods can return either nothing (return type void), a primitive value or an object reference.  If you want it to return 2 primitive values, like two integers, then you need to wrap it in an object which contains two integers.

```
class TwoInts {
    private int first;
    private int second;

    public TwoInts(int first, int second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

    public int getFirst() {
        return first;
    }

    public int getSecond() {
        return second;
    }
}

// in your other class
class TestTwoInts {
    TwoInts getInts() {
        return new TwoInts(1, 2);
    }
}
```

> and lastly how do I get Java to print information from other methods?

`System.out.println` is accessible from anywhere in any Java program.  It doesn't matter from which methods you call it.

> I have a question where I need to print a line that takes information from 2 other methods I've made.

What is the question?

Comment: Hi Brandon my apologies for the question being unclear I have just awoken and trying to get through this, I believe the question is meant to be robust so whatever the int input is it will calculate the highest of two values? With the second question I meant for a return statement I need to return values in dollars and cents, ie input is int 3, int 5 it needs to return 350. so I need to know how to combined 3 with 5 then I can just multiply by 100..

Comment: Either express it in dollars using a float or express it in cents and multiple dollars by 100 to convert.  For example, $3.50 could just be (3 * 100) + 50 = 350.  Or use an object like the one I showed you, with an int for dollars and an int for cents.  Though, honestly, for such a simple use case, that is over-engineering I think.